# Android app keeps 'closing', but no errors being shown in logcat

Tags: android, logcat

This is my main class that will be forwarding the username to my GoalActivity class. I cannot figure out where the issue is. It keeps crashing for an unknown reason to me. I've followed various tutorials, and I cannot figure out the issue. It seems that I retrieve the username correctly, and then convert it into a string. Then create an Intent and pass the username value with a key.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.agray.carpediem.LoginDataBaseAdapter;
import com.example.agray.carpediem.R;
import com.example.agray.carpediem.SignUPActivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //create  instance of SQLite Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        //create reference to the buttons used
        btnSignIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIN);
        btnSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUP);

        // Signup button w/onclick listener
        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                /// Create Intent for SignUpActivity
                Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUPActivity.class);
                //start the activity w/intent
                startActivity(intentSignUP);
            }
        });
    }
    // Methods to handleClick Event of Sign In Button
    public void signIn(View View)
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
        dialog.setTitle("Login");

        //get the References of views
        final  EditText editTextUserName=
                (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
        final  EditText editTextPassword=
                (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

        Button btnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

        //Signin Button w/ onClickListener
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                //store username and password as strings
                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                //fetch the Password from the DB for respective username
                String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSingleEntry(userName);

                // check if the Stored password matches with  Password entered by user
                if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login is Successful " + userName,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();

//                    final  EditText editTextUserName=
//                            (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
//                    String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                    //create intent that will start the goals activity w/some data
                    Intent intro = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GoalActivity.class);

                    //put the username into intent
                    intro.putExtra("USER_NAME", userName);
                    startActivity(intro);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Access Denied: User Name or Password " +
                                    "does not match",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Close The Database
        loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

Here is my GoalActivity class that receives info from the MainActivity class.

GoalActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GoalActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.goals_page);

        //get the username from the intent
        String enteredUserName = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_NAME");

        final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.user_name_forwarded);
        tv.setText(enteredUserName);
    }

}
```

login.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUserNameToLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPasswordToLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignIn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In" />

</LinearLayout>
```

goals_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome_goals"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/user_name_forwarded"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.agray.carpediem" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="CarpeD"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.agray.carpediem.MainActivity"
            android:label="CarpeD" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SignUPActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".GoalActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try to close and re-open your eclipse

Comment: You can get the stack trace?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio..

Comment: Post the code where you transfer data in GoalActivity.java.

Comment: @Daniel, Not sure what you are asking, the code where I aim to transfer starts where you see Intent intro in the MainActivity.java.

Comment: btw... why are u referencing your edit text so late on the click handler. Initialize them and reference them on your onCreate and just put/set the values on your signIn(View View).

Comment: What you are alleging just doesn't happen.  If your app is "crashing" there will be mention of that fact in logcat, and you need to include that in your post.

Comment: @Chris, okay then. Fixed.

Comment: @user3413605 post the manifest

Comment: Comment your signIn method code & then run it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, e.g. in `ActivityA`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("USER_NAME", userNameString);
startActivity(i);
```

In `ActivityB`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
    return;
}

String USERNAME = extras.getString("USER_NAME");
```

Comment: Still same issue. It initializes just fine, but as soon as I login with the correct info, it crashes.

Comment: Add the code above where it says `ActivityB` to your `GoalActivity`.. that will correctly receive the userName string from previous activity. If an error shows up, then it must be from something else and we need more details of the error so we can help

Comment: What info do you need? It is still crashing. The xml code of both classes?

Comment: BTW, it runs perfectly when I had it just making a Toast.. as soon as I tried to transfer data...it crashes everytime.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to check the `TextView`'s ID and see if it's correct.. If it is, try to display another string (not the transferred data) and see what happens.

Comment: Boo. The ID is correct, quadruple checked it. Have it making a Toast showing the userName and works just fine.

Comment: It won't even transition to next screen.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was a very careless mistake. I had updated all the other activities in the Manifest but the activity tag for the GoalActivity.java. Thanks guys for all your help!